# How to solve the trigonometric equation $2\cos x(3-4\sin^2(2x)) = 1 - 2\cos7x $

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $$\tag{*}
2\cos x(3-4\sin^2(2x)) = 1 - 2\cos7x
$$

I tried many ways, but it didn't work. Guys help me with this.

This is my work
$$
\begin{split}
    (*) \Leftrightarrow & 6\cos x - 4(1-\cos4x)\cos x -1 + 2\cos7x = 0\\
        \Leftrightarrow & 2\cos x + 4\cos4x*\cos x - 1 + 2\cos7x = 0\\
        \Leftrightarrow & 2(\cos x + \cos7x) + 4\cos4x*\cos x -1 = 0\\
        \Leftrightarrow & 4\cos4x*\cos3x + 4\cos4x*\cos x -1 = 0\\
        \Leftrightarrow & 4\cos4x(\cos3x + \cos x) -1 = 0\\
        \Leftrightarrow & 4\cos4x(4\cos^3(x) -2\cos x)-1 = 0\\
        \Leftrightarrow & 8\cos4x*\cos x*\cos2x = 1\\
\end{split}
$$
I got stuck here.

Comment: We are not here to simply answer your homework questions - please add some details about what you have tried so far. If you truly cannot get started, then listing some techniques you have been taught about to solve similar problems means that we can write answers that are at the right level of knowledge for you

Comment: linoess9a Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if $\sin x=0, x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

otherwise multiply both sides by $\sin x,$

as $\sin y(3-4\sin^2y)=\sin3y,$

$$\sin x(1-2\cos7x)=\sin(3\cdot2x)$$

Using [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)
$$\iff\sin x-(\sin8x-\sin6x)=\sin6x$$

$$\iff\sin8x=\sin x$$

Comment: @labbhttacharjee .Thanks a lot. You help me improve my taking insight in math problems

Comment: @ViệtAnh, Please follow : https://ia902900.us.archive.org/13/items/planetrigonometr01lone/planetrigonometr01lone.pdf and https://ia800702.us.archive.org/27/items/treatiseonplanet00hobs/treatiseonplanet00hobs.pdf